# Colour of ocean water

Tags: visible-light

Why does ocean  water seem blue colour in some regions while green in some regions while river of pond water is never blue in colour?

Comment: Water is blue.  If it looks green, it's because it's got green stuff in it (e.g., algae).  If you look into clear blue water next to a bright white Carribean beach, then what's really going on is, you are looking _through_ the blue water at the white sandy bottom.  Ponds and rivers practically never have a white sandy bottom.  Try looking into a swimming pool instead.

Answer (score 1):

The ocean is blue because blue light is at the end of the visible spectrum. The wavelengths(lower energy) that produce red, yellow, green etc. are readily absorbed while the the photons that penetrate the depths correspond to blue and reflect that way. In shallow waters, green will be reflected from the sand or whatever color the sediment is.